# Subtracting days from date

Tags: vb.net, date, visual-studio-2012

I'm struggling in vein to work out how to remove 5 days from today's date...

I have the following simple code that searches compares the result of a text file array search and then compares them to today's date. If the date within the text file is older than today then it deletes, if not it doesn't.

What i want though is to say if the date in the text file is 5 days or older then delete.

This is being used in the English date format.

```
    Sub KillSuccess()
    Dim enUK As New CultureInfo("en-GB")

    Dim killdate As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("d", enUK)

    For Me.lo = 0 To UBound(textcis)
        If textcis(lo).oDte < killdate Then
            File.Delete(textcis(lo).oPath & ".txt")
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: if you want to test a date variable, dont convert it to string.  what Type is the `oDte` property?

Comment: I think what you want is `DateAdd` then add -5 days http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx

Comment: `Now.AddDays(-5.0)` should do the trick.

Comment: Wow, thanks all - I'll look through now. FYI the oDte is in a string format hence why its been converted to string

Comment: for date comparison, you need to use date variables.  convert `oDte` to a date rather than the current date to string as in Amit's answer

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `AddDays` method; in code that would be something like this:

```
Dim today = DateTime.Now
Dim answer = today.AddDays(-5)
```

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx)

Which would make your code

```
Sub KillSuccess()

    Dim killdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5)

    For Me.lo = 0 To UBound(textcis)
        If textcis(lo).oDte < killdate Then
            File.Delete(textcis(lo).oPath & ".txt")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```